# Windows Service Exception Handling and Timers

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, windows-services, system.timers.timer

I've an issue with System.Timers.Timer. 
Precisely it doesn't throw any Exceptions. Here is my code:

```
private Timer MyTimer { get; set; }

public MyService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    MyTimer = new Timer(10 * 1000);
    MyTimer.Elapsed += MyTimer_Elapsed;
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    MyTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(EVENTLOGSOURCE))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(EVENTLOGSOURCE, EVENTLOGDESCRIPTION);
    }
    EventLog.WriteEntry(EVENTLOGSOURCE, "UnhandledException\r\n" + e.ExceptionObject, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    EventLog.WriteEntry(EVENTLOGSOURCE, "UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.IsTerminating: " + e.IsTerminating, EventLogEntryType.Error);

    if (e.IsTerminating)
    {
        this.ExitCode = 100;
        //this.Stop();
    }
}

private void MyTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer.Enabled = false;
    CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(AppDomain.CurrentDomain, new UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(new Exception("FakeExceptionForTestPurposeOnly: It will be logged!"), false));

    Int32 i = Convert.ToInt32("10_ForSureGeneratesException_10");
}
```

So, in my event log i can find "FakeExceptionForTestPurposeOnly: It will be logged!" but it's the only one!

Afterall, the worse part is the service it's still running. **How that even possible?**

**Please note** i already solved the problem, in that case the use of timer is not mandatory. System.Threading.Thread does the trick and works as a clockwork. I'm just curious i guess...

So the question is: **why during the occurrence of any UnhandledExceptions in MyTimer_Elapsed() "CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)" never will be fired?**

Any helps, suggestions, comments will be appreciated

Comment: this.Stop(); is commented??!!

Comment: yes it is :-) but it doesn't matter. The reason for the presence of "this.Stop();" it's merely realted to prevent service autorestart during debug (cause windows handles restart of the service when stops with errors). The issue it's "MyTimer doesn't fire UnhandledException"

Comment: Can you add a little more explanation? You say you're curious about *something* but I've no idea what you're curious about. What did you expect to happen and what did/didn't happen that didn't match your expectations?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever during my last edit i just added what i'm courious about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Windows Service, the "Main" thread is owned by the `Service Control Manager`, which is who calls the `OnStart` and `OnStop` methods. When an exception occurs on its "Main" thread, the `ServiceBase` class is in charge of exception handling, thus takes care of the exception and doesn't propagate it up the call chain.

Although there should be no `SynchronizationContext` inside a Windows Service, hence the `Elapsed` event should be fired on a different `ThreadPool` thread, i would suggest you to try `System.Threading.Timer` instead, and see if the exception propagates when the `Elapsed` event calls your callback.

Comment: You're right the problem is the synchronization context. [synchronizingobject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx)